# systemd-path service not working

Tags: linux, systemd, inotify

I have added a systemd service to monitor a path, but it is not working. I touched a .txt file under /tmp/test/, but it is not kicking in my service. I can't see "/tmp/testlog.txt" getting generated. Is there anything wrong in my service?

myservice.path

```
[Unit]
Description=Path Exists

[Path]
PathExistsGlob=/tmp/test/*.txt
PathChanged=/tmp/test/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

myservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'mkdir /tmp/test && sleep 60'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo "Test Success" >> /tmp/testlog.txt & '

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

tmp dir:

```
# ls /tmp/test/
ab.txt
#
```

What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542430/inotify-and-bash

Comment: Please also show `systemctl status myservice.path`.  I think it needs to be started (and enabled, if you want it to be started on boot).

Comment: Also `journalctl --since=-1day -u myservice.service` would show if there was an error running the service.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44707458/12231187) on SO. Please delete one of the question instances, as per site usage guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a timing issue. I added dependency and made this service to start as the very last one. That one solved the issue.

Comment: Which dependency did you add? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: I have a series of my own custom services. Added dependency using the keyword "After" and made this service running as the very last one. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem; try adding the following in the `[Unit]` section:

```
Wants=observer.service
```

Comment: Why though? There's no explanation of why this solves the issue.